# Como mostrar los resultados de una array de mayor a menor

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en java y en uno de los ejercicios de practica tengo lo siguiente:

> Crea un array con 6 nombres de alumnos y un array con las respectivas
> notas que  han obtenido en una prueba (por orden correlativo). Muestra
> primero la lista de  aprobados y luego la lista de suspensos. Indica
> también cuantos aprueban y cuantos  suspenden.

Yo con mis conocimientos hasta ahora he podido crear lo siguiente:

```
int[] notas = { 5, 4, 6, 5, 4, 1 };

    String[] alumnos = { "Xavi", "Nacho", "Arnau", "Denis", "Wiliam", "David" };

    for (int i = 0; i < alumnos.length; i++) {

        if (notas[i] >= 5) {
            System.out.println(alumnos[i] + " " + notas[i]);
        }}
```

Solo he conseguido que muestre los alumnos con notas aprobadas, y no se como proceder a mostrar el resto de la array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para mostrar el resto del array se puede hacer otro ciclo *for* con un condicional *if* que sólo imprima los alumnos con notas menores a *5*:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < alumnos.length; i++) {
    if (notas[i] < 5) {
      System.out.println(alumnos[i] + " " + notas[i]); 
    }
  }
```

Para la segunda parte del ejercicio

> Indica también cuantos aprueban y cuantos suspenden.

Es posible crear dos variables contadoras e incluirlas en los ciclos *for* para ir contando la cantidad de alumnos que cumplen la condición aprobado = (nota >= 5) o reprobado = (nota < 5). El código quedaría así:

```
int[] notas = { 5, 4, 6, 5, 4, 1 };
String[] alumnos = { "Xavi", "Nacho", "Arnau", "Denis", "Wiliam", "David" };
int alumnosAprobados = 0; // variable contadora de número de alumnos aprobados.
int alumnosReprobados = 0; // variable contadora de número de alumnos reprobados.

System.out.println("Alumnos Aprobados:");
for (int i = 0; i < alumnos.length; i++) {
  if (notas[i] >= 5) {
    System.out.println(alumnos[i] + " " + notas[i]);
    alumnosAprobados++; // esto significa que va a hacer alumnosAprobados + 1, es decir aumenta de 1 en 1 cada vez que se cumple la condición (hay un alumno aprobado). 
  }
}
System.out.println("Alumnos Reprobados:");
for (int i = 0; i < alumnos.length; i++) {
  if (notas[i] < 5) {
    System.out.println(alumnos[i] + " " + notas[i]);
    alumnosReprobados++; // esto significa que va a hacer alumnosReprobados + 1, es decir aumenta de 1 en 1 cada vez que se cumple la condición (hay un alumno reprobado). 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente agrega un else en donde imprimas los alumnos que no aprobaron

```
int[] notas = { 5, 4, 6, 5, 4, 1 };
String[] alumnos = { "Xavi", "Nacho", "Arnau", "Denis", "Wiliam", "David" };

for (int i = 0; i < alumnos.length; i++) {

    if (notas[i] >= 5) {
        System.out.println("aprobado: " + alumnos[i] + " " +notas[i] );
    }else{
        System.out.println("suspenso: " + alumnos[i] + " " +notas[i] );
    }
}
```

Salida

```
aprobado: Xavi 5
suspenso: Nacho 4
aprobado: Arnau 6
aprobado: Denis 5
suspenso: Wiliam 4
suspenso: David 1
```

Tambien puedes definir 2 arrayList en donde almacenas los alumnos aprobados y los suspensos, posteriormente imprimes estos valores

```
int[] notas = { 5, 4, 6, 5, 4, 1 };
String[] alumnos = { "Xavi", "Nacho", "Arnau", "Denis", "Wiliam", "David" };

List<String> aprobados = new ArrayList<>();   
List<String> suspensos = new ArrayList<>();


for (int i = 0; i < alumnos.length; i++) {

    if (notas[i] >= 5) {
         aprobados.add(alumnos[i]);
        System.out.println(alumnos[i] + " " +notas[i] );
    }else{
        suspensos.add(alumnos[i]);
    }
}



System.out.println("aprobados: " + aprobados);
System.out.println("suspensos: " + suspensos);
```

salida

```
aprobados: [Xavi, Arnau, Denis]
suspensos: [Nacho, Wiliam, David]
```

Comment: Al poner el "else" a continuación me sale "suspenso: Nacho 4" en la segunda posición y tendría que salir primero los aprobados, no entiendo por que aparece eso...

Comment: Ok @Azumay404 deseas ordernar primero los que pasaron y luego los que no.

Comment: Si correcto, ya lo logré haciendo una comparación " if (notas[i] >= 5) ". Gracias por tú ayuda!